# Filling in a multi-choice field in a Sharepoint Doc-Lib using SetDocsMetaInfo Frontpage Server Extentions RPC method

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint, metadata, frontpage-extensions

I've been given a big chunk of code which eventually calls upon the SetDocsMetaInfo method from Frontpage Server Extension RPC.  This is easy enough for most document uploading and property updating, except when dealing with multichoice fields.  I've been scouring through MSDN and I can't find anything on how to fill in multiple values for such a field.

The general syntax for properties is something like this: [SR|default], with the type (string in this case) followed by a pipe and then the value to be written.  Does anyone know the syntax for multichoice fields?

references:
[MSDN: SetDocsMetaInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd587746(v=office.11).aspx)

Comment: Found another reference out there - http://rob-dev.blogspot.com/2005/07/fprpc-mystery-solved.html Trying "\;#" as a delimiter doesn't cause an error, as ";#" does, but also leaves the metadata field empty. Maybe this could give someone out there an idea.

Answer (score 3):

Did you try separating values with ;# like this:
;#Choice 1;#Choice 2;#

In webservices (Lists.UpdateListItems) that does the trick, perhaps that works in RPC too.

Comment: with the ;# before and after the list as a whole?

Comment: Yes, and as separators between the elements.

Comment: Doesn't work, I just keep getting the same "The underlying connection was closed: The connection was closed unexpectedly" error.  I don't think I can use semicolons, since those are the delimiters between different metadata elements.

Comment: I don't have a FPPRC test project so I can't easily try it for you, but what I'd do is look with Fiddler (http://www.fiddler2.com) to see what data is going accross. If you're in C/C++/C#, make sure the \ itself is escaped in your code (\\\).

Comment: Thanks for this. I was having the same problem and could not find documentation ANYWHERE on it.  The delimiter formatting and escaping the semi colon made this work for me.

Answer (score 1):

Setting it up like Eric suggested works!!!!

Here is how I setup my hashtable that I use to store my metadata

```
    Dictionary<string, object> properties = new Dictionary<string, object>(); 
    properties.Add("Title", "Test Title");
    properties.Add("PermitApplicationID", 12);
    //this next line is a metadata field that is a "choice type" field in sharepoint
    properties.Add("DocumentCategories", ";#SP;#FP;#EC;#");
```